# Mysql regex quirks

Tags: mysql, regex

Why does this match (it should match (44[0-9]) zero or more times)

```
mysql> SELECT "tampampam" REGEXP "(44[0-9])*$";
+----------------------------------+
| "tampampam" REGEXP "(44[0-9])*$" |
+----------------------------------+
|                                1 |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And this does not (it should match 44 followed by ([0-9]) zero or more times

```
mysql> SELECT "44tampampam" REGEXP "44([0-9])*$";
+------------------------------------+
| "44tampampam" REGEXP "44([0-9])*$" |
+------------------------------------+
|                                  0 |
+------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a very strange regex expression.

As for the first case, `(44[0-9])*$` means "match a string starting with `44` and then a number from 0 to 9, any number of times up to the end of string". Since "any number" is possible, the string "tampampam" is matched.

As for the second case, `44([0-9])*$` means "match `44`, then any number from 0 to 9 (with heavy backtracking), zero or more times, up to the end of string". But after `44` there is "tampampam". No match is due. Remove `$`, and you'll have a match.

Comment: More specifically, "match any number of times" means that matching **zero** times is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You must use start anchor also to make sure it doesn't match unwanted text:

```
SELECT "tampampam" REGEXP "^(44[0-9])*$";
+-----------------------------------+
| "tampampam" REGEXP "^(44[0-9])*$" |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The first query matches because matching something zero or more times, means that not matching it (ie. matching zero times), is also a match.

The second query does not match, because you have anchored the regular expression to the end of the string, because of the dollar-sign (`$`). As the end of the string is not the string `44` optionally followed by digits, it does not match.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to use `*$` in your case. Keep it simple:

```
SELECT "tampampam" REGEXP "44[0-9]";
```

**=> 0**

```
SELECT "t441ampampam" REGEXP "44[0-9]";
```

**=> 1**

```
SELECT "t441ampampam" REGEXP "^44[0-9]";
```

**=> 0**

```
SELECT "441tampampam" REGEXP "^44[0-9]";
```

**=> 1**

So if you need **44** to be the first characters in the string use `'^44[0-9]'`.

If you don't care that is as simple as `'44[0-9]'`.